# Is there a Do/Bind pattern to create an object containing different types in fp-ts?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I’m looking for something like `Record.Do` with `Record.bind` so I can do something like this

```
function getB: (a:A) => B
function getC: (b: B) => C
function getD: (c: C) => D

type Z = {
  a: A,
  b: B,
  c: C,
  d: D,
}

const getZ = (a: A): Z => pipe(
  R.Do,
  R.bind('a', () => a),
  R.bind('b', () => getB(a)),
  R.bind('c', (bindings) => getC(bindings.b)),
  R.bind('d', (bindings) => getD(bindings.c)),
)
```

I basically want to construct an object of different types while retaining all the inner objects of different types before applying some transformations on them

Not sure how to go about achieving this. I don’t want to take my types to other domains like `Option`, `Either`, `IO`; I feel like that just adds more code using `O.some`(s) or `E.right`(s) or `IO.of`(s) for transformations that don’t error.

This is the closes I could get

```
const getZ = (a: A): Z => pipe(
  IO.Do,
  IO.bind('a', () => () => a),
  IO.bind('b', () => () => getB(a)),
  IO.bind('c', (bindings) => () => getC(bindings.b)),
  IO.bind('d', (bindings) => () => getD(bindings.c)),
)()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the do notation on the Identity module? It's a type without any effects, so it should do what you want: https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Identity.ts.html#do-notation

Answer (score 0):

The imperative way to do this would be

```
const getZ = (a:A): Z => {
   const b = getB(a)
   const c = getC(b)
   const d = getD(c)
   return ({a, b, c, d})
}
```

More fp-ts, but still kinda imperative?

```
const getZ = (a: A): Z => pipe(
  a,
  (a) => ({ b: getB(a), a}),
  (bindings) => ({ c: getC(bindings.b), ...bindings })
  (bindings) => ({ d: getD(bindings.c), ...bindings })
)
```

Still looking for suggestions